# Compile PSTricks image in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, pstricks, inkscape

I want to compile [this.](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xfkgmpfsvhjk) `PSTricks` image but it does not work in LaTeX. It was exported from `Inkscape` I have tried to compile it by doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[ht]
\input{Figures/drawing.tex}
\caption{Figure example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But it shows a lot of errors. Can someone give me a hand with that?

Comment: We don't know the error and we don't know what code caused the error. How much help would you be able to give somebody in that case? The code you provide here should allow us to reproduce the error and you should include the exact text of the error message. (Your question should not depend on the content of an external link which will render it meaningless when that link changes.)

Comment: @cfr, the error is this: `Undefined control sequence. }`. For many lines in the `image.tex` file

Comment: Oh, that's a helpful error. It tells you which control sequence is undefined. (You've left this bit out, but it is there.) So just load the relevant package or define whatever you've forgotten.

Comment: Well, I do not know exactly what I've forgotten because I've followed tutorials but they don't add something new in the lines I've pasted above. Maybe is something wrong with the `image.tex` code?

Comment: The point is: the message tells you what is undefined but you've not told us that bit. So you know but we can only guess - and it could be almost anything, really, aside from the cs's defined by LaTeX, the packages you've loaded and TeX itself. That leaves a whole world of undefined things. Which particular one or ones are included in `image.tex`? We don't know. But the error message has told YOU. Trust it. Whatever it says is undefined probably is.

Comment: `%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions` Note that OverLeaf won't show other people the errors, I don't think. Only you.

Comment: Actually, I am not compiling the code in OverLeaf. I just put the `image.tex` code there because it is too long to paste in this forum.

Comment: As long as we don't know what is in `drawing.tex`, it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Bernard, `drawing.tex` is in the link that I put in my question.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `drawing.tex`

Comment: For me, the code you posted compiles fine with `pdflatex` if `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` is added to the preamble (*after* pstricks loading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the document with `pdflatex`, but it must be run with `xelatex` or the sequence `latex`->`dvips->ps2pdf`.

If you really need `pdflatex` then use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{tikz}
\else
  \usepackage{pstricks}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \input{Figures/drawing.tex}
        \caption{Figure example}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and run `pdflatex --shell-escape <filename>` 
Then you'll get the image, too.

[image]

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: Sorry for delete my comment. Error: `Package auto-pst-pdf Error: . Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}`. I am using TexStudio running on Ubuntu 16

Comment: In TeXstudio you can choose with options->configure->build or setting the standard compiler to whatever you like. And dont't forget to add the option `--shell-escape` for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I put the `drawing.tex` in the same directory in which the following input file exists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}  
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[ht]
\input{drawing.tex}
\caption{Figure example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Changing the compiler from `PdfLaTex` to `XeLaTex` worked perfectly